# Unity minimap lat/lon calculation offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, maps

I am working as an intern on a program that is a one to one scale of a city in the Netherlands: Groningen.

My job is to make a (mini)map and so I did. only there is one problem. At spawn the position of the player and minimap are aligned but the further you get away from the spawn point the more inaccurate this alignment becomes. I hope someone can help me and see what I'm doing wrong because I am stuck!
Here is the whole miniMapManager. Look at the
double[] translateCoordinates()

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using InfinityCode.OnlineMapsExamples;
using TMPro;
using SimpleJSON;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Globalization;
using Unity.Netcode;


public class miniMapManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button plusButton;
public Button minButton;
public Button mapButton;
public OnlineMaps map;
public OnlineMaps bigMap;
public GameObject bigMapContainer;
public GameObject miniMapContainer;
public OnlineMapsMarkerManager markerManager;
private bool bigMapActive = false;

public double lat = 53.218814f;
public double lon = 6.569044f;
private double latOffset = 0.0080574904785f; // x MIN DEZE waarde is lat
private double lonOffset = 0.04740894445801f; // x PLUS DEZE waarde is lon
public GameObject objectToFollow;
private PlayerManager playerManager;
private UserManager userManager;
private float r_earth = 6378137f;

public TMP_InputField searchInput;
public string nominatimBaseUrl = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=";
public Button searchButton;

bool groningenFound = false;

double player_Lat;
double player_Lon;
public GameObject player_icon;
public float rotationSpeed = 10f;

List<Vector3> otherPlayerPositions = new List<Vector3>();

private void Start()
{
if (plusButton != null)
{
plusButton.onClick.AddListener(OnPlusButtonClick);
}

if (minButton != null)
{
minButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMinButtonClick);
}

if (mapButton != null)
{
mapButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMapButtonClick);
}

if (searchButton != null)
{
searchButton.onClick.AddListener(SetCoordinates);
// Debug.Log("search button geklikt");
}

userManager = UserManager.Instance;
}

void Update()
{
if (bigMapActive)
{
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
{
BigMapClose();
}
}


if(PlayerManager.instance_exists){
playerManager = PlayerManager.Instance;
}

if (playerManager != null)
{
objectToFollow = playerManager.gameObject;
}
else
{
Debug.LogWarning("PlayerManager instance not found.");
}

// is de afwijking er niet omdat die latoffset en lonoffset er steeds opnieuw bijgegooid worden???
player_Lat = translateCoordinates()[0];
player_Lon = translateCoordinates()[1];

if(!bigMapActive){
map.SetPosition(player_Lon, player_Lat);
}

// Voeg de positie van de lokale speler toe aan de lijst met andere spelerposities
otherPlayerPositions = userManager.GetOtherPlayerPositions(NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId);
if(otherPlayerPositions != null){
UpdateOtherPlayerPositions(otherPlayerPositions);
Debug.Log(otherPlayerPositions);
}


if (PlayerManager.Instance != null && player_icon != null)
{
// Zoek het gameobject met de naam "Prefab_Player(Clone)"
GameObject prefabPlayer = GameObject.Find("Prefab_Player(Clone)");

if (prefabPlayer != null)
{
Debug.LogWarning("Alles gevonden, nu nog roteren.");

// Gebruik de rotatie van het specifieke gameobject
Quaternion playerRotation = prefabPlayer.transform.rotation;

// Pas de rotatie toe op player_icon, let op het gebruik van localRotation
player_icon.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localRotation = playerRotation;
Debug.LogWarning("Rotatie toegepast op player_icon.");
}
else
{
Debug.LogWarning("Prefab_Player(Clone) not found.");
}
}
else
{
Debug.LogWarning("Player manager en/of icon not found.");
}
}

public void UpdateOtherPlayerPositions(List<Vector3> playerPositions)
{
// Verwijder eerst alle bestaande markers op de kaart
// markerManager.RemoveAll();

foreach (Vector3 position in playerPositions)
{
double dLat = position.z / r_earth;
double dLon = position.x / (r_earth * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * (float)lat));

double[] result = new double[2];

result[0] = lat - dLat * 180.0 / Mathf.PI - latOffset;
result[1] = lon - dLon * 180.0 / Mathf.PI + lonOffset;

// Creëer een marker voor elke andere speler op de kaart
markerManager.Create(result[1], result[0]);
}
}

double[] translateCoordinates()
{
Debug.LogWarning(lat);
Debug.LogWarning((float)lat);

double dLat = objectToFollow.transform.localPosition.z / r_earth;
// 3.1455
double dLon = objectToFollow.transform.localPosition.x / (r_earth * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * (float)lat));
// 3.15

double[] result = new double[2];

result[0] = lat - dLat * 180.0 / Mathf.PI - latOffset;
result[1] = lon - dLon * 180.0 / Mathf.PI + lonOffset;

return result;
}

private void OnPlusButtonClick()
{
// Debug.Log("Zoom in button");
map.zoom = Mathf.Clamp(map.zoom + 1, 3, 20);
}

private void OnMinButtonClick()
{
// Debug.Log("Zoom out button");
map.zoom = Mathf.Clamp(map.zoom - 1, 3, 20);
}

private void OnMapButtonClick()
{
bigMapContainer.SetActive(true);
miniMapContainer.SetActive(false);
bigMapActive = true;
bigMap.SetPosition(player_Lon, player_Lat);
bigMap.zoom = 16;
}

private void BigMapClose()
{
bigMapContainer.SetActive(false);
miniMapContainer.SetActive(true);
bigMapActive = false;

}

[System.Obsolete]
public void SetCoordinates()
{
string location = searchInput.text;

StartCoroutine(GeocodeLocation(location));
}

[System.Obsolete]
IEnumerator GeocodeLocation(string location)
{
string url = nominatimBaseUrl + WWW.EscapeURL(location);

using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
{
yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

if (webRequest.isNetworkError || webRequest.isHttpError)
{
Debug.LogError("Error: " + webRequest.error);
}
else
{
string json = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
JSONNode parsedData = JSON.Parse(json);
// Debug.Log("request is gemaakt");
Debug.Log(parsedData);

if (parsedData.Count > 0)
{
// Debug.Log("Data is geparsed en opgehaald");
double newLat = parsedData[0]["lat"].AsDouble;
double newLon = parsedData[0]["lon"].AsDouble;

float newLatFloat = (float)newLat; // Zet double om naar float
float newLonFloat = (float)newLon; // Zet double om naar float

bigMap.SetPosition(newLonFloat, newLatFloat);

// if (CheckForGroningen(parsedData))
// {
// bigMap.SetPosition(newLonFloat, newLatFloat);
// }
// else
// {
// Debug.LogWarning("Dit is niet in Groningen.");
// }
}
}
}
}
}
```

Here is also a video of it happening:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ntnau6nlz0

as you can see I calculated the x/z position to m and based on that give it a lat/lon but somewhere something goes wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess but have you tried rather using `double` for all your calculations? This might not be the entire issue but at least should reduce the effect.

Currently you are using `Mathf` which uses `float` (see [Source code of Mathf](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs)).

=> Possible that it introduces rounding issues here and there, GPS coords and Lat/Lon at this scale require a lot precision!

If you look into the [Source code of Mathf](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs) it mostly underlying uses [`System.Math`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-8.0) but then casts to `float`.

=> Simply stick to [`System.Math`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-8.0) yourself instead and where things don't exist (e.g. `RadToDegree`) use your own `double` based values:

```
public const double Deg2Rad = Math.PI * 2.0 / 360.0;

public const double Rad2Deg = 1.0 / Deg2Rad;
```

etc

---

Also btw quite inefficient to

- everytime create and return a new array
- call and calculate everything twice for lat and lon

rather use a simple struct and reuse the calculated value like e.g.

```
private readonly struct Coordinates
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }

    public Coordinates(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

and then

```
Coordinates translateCoordinates()
{
    double dLat = objectToFollow.transform.localPosition.z / r_earth;
    double dLon = objectToFollow.transform.localPosition.x / (r_earth * Math.Cos(Deg2Rad * lat));

    return new Coordinates(lat - dLat * 180.0 / Mathf.PI - latOffset, lon - dLon * 180.0 / Mathf.PI + lonOffset);
}
```

and finally

```
var coords = translateCoordinates();
player_Lat = coords.X;
player_Lon = coords.Y;
```

---

also here you don't need the array at all so don't create them:

```
foreach (Vector3 position in playerPositions)
{
    double dLat = position.z / r_earth;
    double dLon = position.x / (r_earth * Math.Cos(Deg2Rad * lat));

    var x = lat - dLat * 180.0 / Math.PI - latOffset;
    var y = lon - dLon * 180.0 / Mathf.PI + lonOffset;

    // Creëer een marker voor elke andere speler op de kaart
    markerManager.Create(y, x);
}
```

---

Finally have in mind that coordinates are actually in lat, lon + height.

Not sure how this is handled in your big map but at large scale earth curvature of course also has an impact which might be an additional issue in your calculations which basically ignore the height.

---

#### Alternatively

why even calculate?

You seem to alreadyove your player in a big map => you could just have a minimap camera pointing downwards following the player and just disable the layers it shouldn't be rendering. Then simply put the minimap content on a dedicated layer that is not rendered by the main camera but only the dedicated minimap camera

=> this way you can be sure it is always rendered at the position where it actually is and align the maps once and for all.